# Make bar graph using highcharts from entries in the database

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I am very new to PHP and Jquery and Javascript and I really need help as to how I can make a graph or chart from the entries in my database. I have this code which I got from Highcharts and I wanted to replace the data like the month, the places and other values in the code with the entries in my database but I just don't know how to do it. Here is the code from Highchart:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});

});
```

I have in my database a table called diagnosis which consists of patient's diagnosis and the date the entry was added, now I want my graph to show the monthly rate of a specific disease or illness in my diagnosis field. Is it possible? If yes, can you please help me with this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a php array of ur data. then use jason_encode(ur_array);

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace one of the series with this:

```
series: [{
name: 'massively overweight',
data: 
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT date(date, '%b') as month, count(*) as cnt FROM diagnosis where illness = 'massively overweight'");

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fat_people = $row['cnt'];
    }

    json_encode($cnt)

    ?>
}, {
```

Answer (score 0):

**current_page.php**

```
<script>
$.post( 'get_graph_data.php"', {'id':'data_id'}, function(data) {
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({data});

})
</script>
```

**get_graph_data.php**

```
//get data from database
// make array like this
array(
"chart"=> array(
"renderTo"=> 'container',
"type"=> 'column'
        ),
        "title"=> array(
            "text"=> 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        ),
        "subtitle"=> array(
            'text'=> array('Source'=> 'WorldClimate.com')
        ),
        'xAxis'=> array(
            'categories'=>array( 
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'));
   so on............
echo json_encode($above_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

How your dates looks like? Because Highcharts use timestamps in miliseconds, so probably you need to parse your date by Date.UTC() or use time in appropriate format.

btw. How your JSON looks like?